# Python: How do I efficiently use exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I have a program containing about 170 lines of code with 5 functions in it currently (which is about 35 lines of code per function). Each function has user input about two times (just so you know, the functions are for things like squaring numbers or multiplication). Also, the input varies quite a bit so I don't *think* I can make a class to just check if there would be bad user input (for e.g., in some places "c" should be valid, whereas in other functions it shouldn't, and making complex parameters to see whether "c" should be valid or not seems like an even *more* inefficient way of doing it).

When I make `try` and `exception`s myself, it results in the size of the program doubling as there is basically just half the code in each function checking for invalid user input. I know once I start on bigger projects, the user input won't literally be half the program most of the time and there it makes sense to do this, but isn't there a more efficient way of doing this for a case similar to mine?

**EDIT:**

```
def power():
    select = input("Enter:\n'f' to find powers of numbers,\n'v' to view powers of "
                   "numbers (such as for study purposes),\n'x' to exit. "
                   "\nEnter what you would like to do: ").lower()
    if select == "f":
        while 1 == 1:
            base = float(input("\nEnter base (enter '0' to exit): "))
            if base == 0:
                print()
                break
            print("\nPower:", pow(base, float(input("Enter exponent: "))))
    if select == "v":
        while 1 == 1:
            until = int(input("\nEnter how many powers you would like to view "
                              "(enter '0' to exit): "))
            if until == 0:
                print()
                break
            exponent = float(input("Enter the exponent: "))
            print("\n'^' indicates \"raised to the power of\"\n")
            for number in range(until):
                print(number, "^", exponent, ": ", pow(number, exponent),
                      sep = "")
    if select == "x":
        return

power()
```

Comment: Exceptions aren't normally used to validate user input. You use exceptions to catch fatal errors that packages throw.

Comment: You should make a function that takes userinput that all the other functions can call, for instance `def userinput(message)` and return `None` or something to indicate bad user input.

Comment: @Aurora that's clearly not true for Python. It is perfectly pythonic to use exceptions for control flow in your code and it is done all the time.

Comment: @Aurora why not? It's fairly common to use exceptions like that in Python, even in standard library.

Comment: Can you post a function of your code? It's clearer to see

Comment: Have you considered using regular expressions to validate your user input? If you're familiar with regular expressions a simple re.match can handle the validation.

Comment: @Torxed you mean like make a class in which one function will check for bad number input etc. and a parameter is used to tell the function whether to check for negative numbers or 0 etc.?

Comment: @Maciek like check for "-" (negative number) before an input where should only be non-negative? Thanks, I think I'll use those.

Comment: @NeelKamath Even more like checking if what the user typed is a number at all. \d is your friend :)